# What is the AZURE terraform equivalent of this Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to assign an azure app to an Azure AD role.

In PowerShell I can do this

```
## Import-Module AzureAD

## The role to assign to your app
$directoryRole = '[Role Name]' # i.e. 'Administrator'
$AppId = "[Guid]"
    
## Find the ObjectID of Role Name
$RoleId = (Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object { $_.displayname -eq $directoryRole }).ObjectId
    
## Add the service principal to the directory role
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $RoleId -RefObjectId $AppId -Verbose
```

How do I do it with terraform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no resource in Terraform to assign an AD role to the service principal. You can get all the resources about AD [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs). But if you don't mind, you can use the [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html) to run the PowerShell command in Terraform. This would be a workaround.